# Настройка Web.Config

Tags: python, парсер

Парсил я себе значит, никого и ничего не трогал и тут случилось страшное. В какой то момент парсер просто перестал работать. Как оказалось, проблема у самого корня. При получения html кода из get запроса выдается не код, а ошибка. Честно, я вообще не знаю, что нужно сделать, чтобы заработало.
И да, операционка MacOs, браузер Opera.

Вот мой код:

```
import datetime
import requests


def parse_timetable(data):
    url = f'https://timetable.spbu.ru/AGSM/StudentGroupEvents/Primary/275100/%s' % data

    request = requests.get(url)

    with open('test.html', 'w') as file:
        file.write(request.text)
        file.close()


now = datetime.datetime.now()
now = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

print(parse_timetable(now))
```

Вот, что выдает:

```
&lt;!-- Web.Config Configuration File --&gt;

&lt;configuration&gt;
    &lt;system.web&gt;
        &lt;customErrors mode=&quot;Off&quot;/&gt;
    &lt;/system.web&gt;
&lt;/configuration&gt;
```

Comment: Приведите [mre]

Comment: Парсер работает нормально, ошибку возвращает сервер. Обратитесь к администраторам сайта по этой проблеме.